# Lua functions -- a simple misunderstanding

Tags: function, lua, lua-table

I'm trying to develop a function which performs math on two values which have the same key:

```
property = {a=120, b=50, c=85}
operator = {has = {a, b}, coefficient = {a = 0.45}}
function Result(x) return operator.has.x * operator.coefficient.x end
print (Result(a))
error: attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'x' (a nil value)
```

The problem is that the function is attempting math on literally 
"operator.has.x" instead of "operator.has.a".

I'm able to call a function (x) return x.something end, but if I try function (x) something.x i get an error.  I need to improve my understanding of functions in Lua, but I can't find this in the manuals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but here is some working code that is based on your code:

```
property = {a=120, b=50, c=85}
operator = {has = {a=2, b=3}, coefficient = {a = 0.45}}
function Result(x) return operator.has[x] * operator.coefficient[x] end
print (Result('a'))
```

Prints '0.9'

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do, precisely! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common gotcha for newcomers to the language. Buried in the Lua manual [somewhere](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.2):

> To represent records, Lua uses the field name as an index. The
>   language supports this representation by providing a.name as syntactic
>   sugar for a["name"].

This explains why your `function Result(x)` is failing. If you translate the syntactic sugar, your function becomes:

```
function Result(x) 
  return operator.has['x'] * operator.coefficient['x']
end
```

Geary already offered a solution to this so I won't reiterate it here.

Comment: Ah, that makes good sense.  I should probably avoid using any substitute notation until I understand how tables work under the hood.